# Block UI thread and not display the label message

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following Thread method:

```
public void messageDelay() 
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); 
}
```

But when I call it, it hand the UI interface and I can not done any operation until the thread is finished.

```
private  void Porcessing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    label1.Text = "start under process..";
    messageDelay();
    label1.Text = "Result";
}
```

This is my main method. Any idea whats wrong I do?

Comment: Uh... you don't have a second thread... it's just pausing your main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) in this case. It is essential for activities that are potentially blocking, such as yours:

```
private async void Porcessing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "start under process..";
    await messageDelay();
    label1.Text = "Result";
}

public async Task messageDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Note the use of `async` all the way down. Check this also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: what is async and await keywords ?

Comment: @AliImran Read the link I have included in the answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ It is essential for activities that are potentially blocking, such as yours (blocking UI in longer operations)

Comment: @AliImran Are you aware of `Deadlock` ?? You should use `async` all the way down. Check this https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BackgroundWorker`. This class create another thread, so UI thread will not block. For example:

```
private  void Porcessing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var worker = new BackgroudWorker(); 
    label1.Text = "start under process..";
    worker.DoWork+=BackgroudAction;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted+=BackgroudActionEnd;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void BackgroudAction(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

private void BackgroudActionEnd( object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text="Result";
}
```

Comment: We have the `async` keyword that has been introduced in C#5 and It is a simplified approach for async programming. I think it should be recommended instead of the old ways like `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Of cource async/await is very easy way for asynchronous. But BackgroudWorker can send report about progress. You can easily rework your code for loading bar for example. In this case Backgroud worker will more flexiblу.

Comment: @Tunduk recommended approach for reporting progress is implementing the `IProgress` interface.